# Virtual space for rectangular selections (at least)

Tags: whitespace, rectangle

In Vim there is the `virtualedit` variable which can be set so that Vim allows the cursor to move past the end of the line always or only when in visual block mode. Is it possible to configure Emacs to do at least one of these?

`picture-mode` is not what I'm looking for because it inserts actual spaces.

I'm on Emacs 24.5 (from the Ubuntu package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common solution in general is to use `artist-mode` (I'm even wondering whether you accidentally tried `picture-mode` instead of this?)

In Emacs 25, `rectangle-mark-mode` has been improved such that you can do this by default, after invoking that with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd>

For usage details, see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Rectangles`

In Emacs 24 the `cua-selection-mode` rectangle editing (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11009599)) allows you to extend the rectangle selection beyond the end of the lines.

Read the commentary in `cua-base.el` for the documentation on "CUA rectangle support".

Comment: `picture-mode` inserts spaces too, and neither one works with C-x SPC. I'll wait for version 25. Thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: `artist-mode` does not insert spaces. You can see this if you extend beyond the end of a line, and then `C-a` and `C-e` to jump to the beginning and end of the line. I see you're right in that this mode doesn't work with `rectangle-mark-mode`, however it works just fine with the original rectangle editing commands on the `C-x r` prefix.

Comment: Yeah, I meant `artist-mode` in the comment. I used `whitespace-mode` to see if it had been inserting spaces, and it had been. I didn't see that the space is removed when the `artist-mode` is disabled.

Comment: I've just read a bit of CUA selection mode documentation. Nifty, thanks for the suggestion!